# What am I missing doing bitwise operations in javascript?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

Trying to bitwise OR a group of values and wrote a some test code that doesn't return what I would expect ( old C programmer ). My test code:

```
// take 3 values from string ( 1,2,3 ) and OR them together
var values="012345678"; // sample characters
var val=0; // int to place single ascii value
var bin=0; // binary value after offset
var total=0; // cumulative total
var pos=1; //where to start pulling characters

// take 3 values from string ( 1,2,3 ) and OR them together
for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
        var singleVal=values[pos++];
        val=Number(singleVal.charCodeAt(0));
        bin=val-48; // position offset by ascii "0" = 48
        total|=bin;
}

// Result should be 7 but always returns the last singleVal
console.log("total: "+total);
```

Comment: Never mind....confused the value with the position. Need to shift position by value ( 1<< val )

Comment: Doh!...Thanks for the replies. As soon as I posted I saw my error. Works fine now.

Comment: Sidenote: JSs type coercion can really simplify your code. `for(let i=0; i<3; i++) total |= 1 << values[pos++];`

Comment: I usual minimize my code like that but I broke it down to individual variables to debug line by line what it was doing.

Answer (score 1):

> Result should be 7 but always returns the last singleVal

with bitwise or the result of `1|2|3` is 3, not 7 (01|10|11 = 11).

Answer (score 0):

If you loop until 7 then the result would be 7:

```
for(let i=0;i<7;i++){
```